# Alguém conhece alguma função que passe as posições do array?

Tags: php, funções

Por exemplo, supondo que tenho o array `[1,2,3]`, troque para `[2,3,1]` e depois para `[3,1,2]`. Estou procurando uma função que juntamente do `for`, possa passar as posições do array.
Ex:

```
for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){
  FUNÇÃO
}
```

Comment: Eu estou pedindo dicas de funções PHP que possam ajudar, pois realmente estou sem rumo na resolução

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução para rearranjar a posição dos valores de um array dessa forma que você quer é combinar [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-shift.php) e [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php) da seguinte forma:

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3);
$primeiro = array_shift($numeros); // Pega o primeiro valor do array
array_push($numeros, $primeiro); // Array push adiciona um valor ao final do array
// ou também $numeros[] = $primeiro faz a mesma coisa que o de cima.
```

Depois coloque tudo isso numa função para facilitar sua vida dessa forma:

```
public function trocaPosicoes(array $coisas){
    $primero = array_shift($coisas);

    return is_null($primeiro) ? $coisas : array_push($coisas, $primeiro);
}
```